# IOS shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation does not autorotate properly on launch for UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft

Tags: ios, orientation, launch, autorotate

I set up my app so that it runs in UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight and UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft.  I have set those values in my plist file, and in my shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation, it will only return YES for those orientations.

This works perfectly for the most part, except on the iPad, where if I held it in LandscapeLeft during launch, my app would end up in portrait mode unless I turn the iPad to LandscapeRight to invoke an orientation change.

Looking through the log, it became evident that "willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation" takes place before applicationDidBecomeActive gets called.  I changed my code so that shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation returns YES for any orientation before applicationDidBecomeActive is called and return YES for my landscape orientations only after applicationDidBecomeActive is called.  Now my app would launch properly in LandscapeLeft as well.  However it doesn't feel right that I should fix it this way and I have no idea why iPad is behaving the way it did.  Would appreciate it if somebody can explain this bit of oddity to me.

Comment: I can't.  I have a similar problem, my app doesn't mind starting landscape left or right but then wants to stay there while you wave the device around.  So I'm saying yes to all landscapes until willRotate, then using that setting and saying no to anything else.  Then I was getting willRotate Left before becomeActive and shouldRotate Right afterwards - by which time I'm saying "no".  After much grief I found your comment and it's saved me.  Another weird iOS workaround but what are you gonna do?  Thanks.